# Downloading zipped PNGs in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing an R Shiny application (that I want to host on the Shiny server) that will download PNGs from an API, display them onscreen and then allow the user to download them as a .zip file. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to zip the PNGs. I have managed to get the app to prompt a PNG download when run locally. The code is below. I appreciate any help.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
        titlePanel("Modified Script"),
    
        sidebarLayout(
            inputPanel(
                textInput("URL","TEXT", ""),
                submitButton("Update View", icon("refresh"))),
    
            mainPanel(
                htmlOutput("images"),
                
                    titlePanel('Downloading Data'),
                    sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                            downloadButton('imgs', 'Download')
                        ),
                        mainPanel()
                    )
                )
            
                )
        )
    )
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 imgFiles <- reactiveValues(mat=NULL)
        
 output$images <- renderText({
      dURL = input$URL
      dId = gsub("\\?.*","",gsub('.*/', '', dURL))
      dJson = paste0('[api Location]',dID,'/export/json')
        
        tech = GET(dJSON)
        data = fromJSON(rawToChar(tech$content))
        
        nImage = data$image
        nName = data$name
            
       
        withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
          # Number of times we'll go through the loop
        n <- length(nImage)
        
        count<-0
        images1<-NULL
        images2<-NULL
        destFile<-NULL
        for (x in nImage){
          destFile = paste0(nName[(count+1)],'.png')
          images = c('<img src="',x,'" width=10% height=10%>',images)

          Sys.sleep(.69)
          count = count+1
          
          incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", x))
         
          imgFiles$html <- image1
          imgFiles$imgs <- nImage
          imgFiles$names<- nName
          
           }     
        })
        print(imgFiles$html)
        
       })
      
 output$imgs<-renderText({
   
   as.vector(imgFiles$imgs)
 })
})
```

Comment: This might help you.
https://mastering-shiny.org/action-transfer.html#download

Comment: @MritiAgarwal I know that downloadHandler is where the answer to this ultimately lies. I have tired to work out a content function that will allow me to zip() the PNGs together, and nothing seems to work. THIS works locally, but prompts for each individual file to be saved. Once it's on the server, it only prompts the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to make it work by using `tar` rather than `zip`. I am going to play around with it some more, but this seems to work on the Shiny Server.

```
 output$imgs <- downloadHandler(
       filename = "DownloadPNGs.tar",
       
       content = function(file){
        
          tmpdir <- tempdir()
          setwd(tempdir())
          count<-0
          for (i in imgFiles$imgs){
            path <-paste0(imgFiles$names[count+1],".png")
            download.file(i,path,mode="wb")
            Sys.sleep(.69)
            count=count+1
       }
        tar(tarfile = file,files=tmpdir)
    }
     )
```